# PPT VBA Send trigger from ppt shape to Chart data

Tags: vba, powerpoint

have formatted the code as below. Error comes as data member not found at ".Sheets(1).Range("A7").Value"

```
 Sub DATA()
 temp = 0
 ActivePresentation.Slides(4).Shapes("Temp").TextFrame.TextRa‌​nge.Text = ActivePresentation.Slides(4).Shapes("Temp").TextFrame.TextRa‌​nge.Text +1 'counter to add +1
 With ActivePresentation.Slides(4).Shapes("Bar1").Chart.ChartData 
    .Activate 
    .Sheets(1).Range("A7").Value = ActivePresentation.Slides(4).Shapes("Temp").TextFrame.TextRa‌​nge.Text
    .Workbook.Close 
End With 
End Sub
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly and detail what isn't working for you. I.e. "I can't get the value from a table data source in powerpoint" or "how do I use the next button in presentation mode to run a subroutine?".

Comment: Please use the {} button to format your code.

Comment: In simple terms I need to populate cell a1 of ChartData with "10"

Comment: In simple terms I need to populate cell a1 of ChartData with "10"              {With ActivePresentation.Slides(4).Shapes("Bar1").Chart.ChartData.range("a1").value = 10                                  end with}

Comment: Understood, but what is your *problem*? Is there an error? If so, what is the error? If not an error, describe how the results are not what you expect them to be.

Answer (score 0):

The `ChartData` object refers to the entire `Workbook`, so you're probably getting an error like 438: Object does not support this property or method, because `Cell` is not a child of `Workbook` object.

NB also, `Cell` is not a child of `Worksheet` object, either, it's `Cells` or `Range` that you need, and you'll need to qualify that to a worksheet, like `Sheets(1)` (modify as needed).

So, try:

```
Dim val$
val = ActivePresentation.Slides(4).Shapes("temp").textrange.text
With ActivePresentation.Slides(4).Shapes("Bar1").Chart.ChartData
    '.Activate
    ' something like this:
    .Sheets(1).Range("A1").value = val
    .Workbook.Close
End With
```

In theory you're supposed to be able to use a `With` block to manage the `ChartData` object. In practice, I have *always* had to actually `Activate` it and subsequently close it. YMMV.

Comment: Hi , tried your answer but getting error, " data member not found" below is the script and error is @ ".Sheets(1).Range("A7").Value".

Comment: Sub DATA()

temp = 0
 ActivePresentation.Slides(4).Shapes("Temp").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = ActivePresentation.Slides(4).Shapes("Temp").TextFrame.TextRange.Text + 1 ' counter to add +1

With ActivePresentation.Slides(4).Shapes("Bar1").Chart.ChartData
    .Activate
    .Sheets(1).Range("A7").Value = ActivePresentation.Slides(4).Shapes("Temp").TextFrame.TextRange.Text
    .Workbook.Close
End With

End Sub

Comment: please revise your question it's not easy to read code in comments because it won't format properly.

Comment: Try changing to `.Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").value = val`?

Comment: Thanks David, its working now...just a flash of excel data source comes for a fraction of second. any idea to remove it...otherwise everything is working perfectly...thanks a lot for all your help

Comment: I've never been able to disable the Excel flash unfortunately

Comment: anyway np..Thanks for all your help. Is there any thing I need to do to close this Question..

Comment: Questions are never truly "closed" here unless by moderator, but you can mark it as accepted if it's solved the problem.